# Adding text to every 3rd marker on a Matplotlib line chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, text, annotations

I have created the below chart with text at each data point.  What I want is for it to show every 3rd text on the marker.Line would remain, but the text for each data point should skip two.  So I would expect to see the same line, but text on only 10%, 40%, 70% and 100%.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
y = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct']

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(x,y)), columns=['Percentages', 'Months'])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(df['Months'], df['Percentages'], color='#0076B6', dashes=[6, 2], marker='o')
for j, v in enumerate(df['Percentages']):
    ax.text(j, v+2, str('{:.2f}'.format(round(v, 2)))+'%', fontsize=5.5, horizontalalignment='center')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Hope that makes sense and someone can help out.

Thanks in advance,

Aksel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop only over every third element:

```
for j, v in enumerate(df['Percentages'][::3]):
    ax.text(j*3, ...)
```